# GraphQL - impossibility to Ram-caching data is a big weakness for GraphQL?

Tags: caching, graphql, apollo, relay, in-memory

I'm interesting in data query language and seems that jsonApi is dead and now it is graphQL that occupies the scene. But GraphQL doesn't support caching data so I'm wondering if this point is just a dead point for GraphQL since in-memory data [of Apollo or Relay] can't rivalize with HTTP-caching data if I follow some articles written on the web.

I see a lot of people beating around the bush. Above any opiniated discussion, concretely in term of performances, this in-memory caching is a dead point for GraphQL ? Or it's okay to run with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is a query language (like SQL). It is not concerned with caching as such.

It is true that POST requests don't work well with standard HTTP caching, but there are various extensions that enable caching from server-side, e.g. Apollo Engine: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/caching.html

Comment: So GET requests work well with HTTP caching if I understand you ?

Comment: Yes, HTTP caching is typically used with GET requests.
Some GraphQL implementations work purely over POST, but it's now common to support GET for queries i.e. with the aforementioned Apollo Engine.

Comment: Okay I see, hence the Apollo Engine (or other package available fort this process) request are normally cached as would be any other REST GET request if I follow you